# handle undefined data in neural networks

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing a neural network project in which there is a feature that is the time passed from the user's last activity until some specific times. For example imagine that there is a list of times (March 15th, April 1st, April 24th, etc) and we want to find the interval between each user last activity before any of those specific times and the specific time. To be more clear, image `user1` has some actions on March 10th, March 13th and March 24th, the values for him/her according to March 15th would be 2 days (March 13th). Now what if the user has no actions before March 15th?

Now due to some algorithms, I am joining some temp tables which result in having lots of `NaN`. How to tell the network that these cells should not be considered?

---

***edit1***

the code to fill the cell is this:

```
for aciton_time in all_aciton_times:
    interval_tmp = actions_df.loc[(actions_df['when'] < aciton_time)].drop_duplicates(subset="device_id", keep='last')
    interval_tmp['aciton_' +  str(aciton_time)] = interval_tmp['when'].apply(lambda x: aciton_time - x)
    del interval_tmp['when']
    interval = interval.merge(interval_tmp, on="device_id", how="outer")
    previous_aciton_time = aciton_time
```

and the result is something like this:

[image: screenshot]

thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code involving the problem?

Comment: please check the post update

Comment: Search online on how to handle missing data. Essentially bottom line, when data is missing, *some* compromise has to be made one way or another. Drop rows, impute values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large dataset you could drop any rows that have NaN values

Comment: yes the dataset is large but I cannot drop these rows, because my dataset is badly imbalanced (more than 99% is labeled 0) and these rows are all related to 1s and if I delete them, I would make the dataset even more imbalanced